# cold water odor from bathroom sink faucet

Tags: bathroom, water, smell

Our home is 3 years old and we have city water. We have dual sinks in our bathroom. When the cold water is turned on in only the left sink, an odor starts about 4 seconds later and then goes away. No other faucet throughout the house has this issue. What might be the reason for the smell?[image]
[image]

First pictures are of left side of plumbing under sink (right side is the cold water line) and the last two pictures are under the second sink, which has no order.

[image]

Comment: we need a picture from under the counter to see your plumbing

Comment: Added a picture. I saw a similar post and the person answering said that the he had a slight “s” bend in the braided line and the smell was trapped in this bend. The person straightened the line and the smell disappeared. Could this possibly be a solution?

Comment: We need to see both sinks, and the *entirety* of each sink's drain piping.

Comment: Does the odor happen if you run the cold water into a container, rather than down the drain? *Most* "sink odor" issues come from the drain, with trap/venting problems.

Comment: I will check this suggestion out.